# Flutter convert currency format

Tags: flutter, dart

for example ***+100286020524,17*** how to become ***Rp 100.286.020.524,17*** and remove this sign **+** . how to implement in dart flutter

**EDIT**
this mycode
I using indonesia: 1.0.1 packages

```
main() {
  rupiah(123456789); // Rp 123,456,789
}
```

I've tried like this:

```
replaceAll(new RegExp(r'[^\w\s]+'),'')
```

but not i hope output.
how to remove symbol plus

Comment: Have you tried something on your own first? If yes, what doesn't work yet?

Comment: above mycode. I can't remove sign "+"

Comment: Try taking a look at [RegExp](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/RegExp-class.html)

Comment: how to using RegExp?

Comment: Click on the link I added. It's the documentation for RegExp, if you read it through you'll find out how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To easily format values according to a locale it is recommended to use [intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl).

A currency can be formatted like this for Indonesia:

```dart
double d = 100286020524.17;
final currencyFormatter = NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'ID');
print(currencyFormatter.format(d)); // IDR100.286.020.524,17
```

You can also use classic formatting:

```dart
double d = 100286020524.17;
final currencyFormatter = NumberFormat('#,##0.00', 'ID');
print(currencyFormatter.format(d)); // 100.286.020.524,17
```

In this second way you will have only the value formatted without the currency symbol.

Comment: You can do something like this, but there might be a better way: ```String value = "+100286020524,17";
    value = value.replaceAll('+', '');
    value = value.replaceAll(',', '.');
    print(double.parse(value)); ```